# Is endl a method, and if it is can it take arguments?

Tags: c++, methods

I was using my code::blocks v10.05 compiler when I came across something strange. It when I was about to add a carriage return, it suggested endl, and then automatically put this:

```
    cout << "The age of " + age + " isn't that bad. Embrace it" << endl();
```

can the endl method take parameters?

Answer (score 11):

[`endl`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/endl/) is a manipulator function:

```
ostream& endl ( ostream& os );
```

You can either concatenate it to a stream:

```
cout << endl;
```

Or pass a stream as an argument to the function:

```
endl(cout);
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't know about that but apparently we can pass an Output stream to it
here is what i found online :)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/endl/

Comment: You may want to be careful with cplusplus.com. It is notoriously wrong and thus an unreliable source when you want to look up library documentation.

Comment: @bitmask thanks for the heads up , I ll cross reference that will other sites from now on :)